# Undefined variable: insert

Tags: php, laravel

I intend to insert image link like that "annonces\ August2020 \ image.jpg" into the db and image in storage but it gives me error Undefined variable: insert.

**FileController.php**

```
public function save(Request $request)
    {
       request()->validate(['file'  => 'required|mimes:doc,docx,pdf,txt,jpeg,jpg|max:2048',]);

       if ($files = $request->file('fileUpload')) {
           $destinationPath = 'public/file/'; // upload path
           $profilefile = date('YmdHis') . "." . $files->getClientOriginalExtension();
           $files->move($destinationPath, $profilefile);
           $insert['file'] = "$profilefile";
        }
        $check = Document::insertGetId($insert);
        return Redirect::to("file")
        ->withSuccess('Great! file has been successfully uploaded.');
    }
```

**file.balde.php**

```
<form action="/save" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="file" id="file" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
                    <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Please upload a valid image file. Size of image should not be more than 2MB.</small>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('file', 'fileController@index');
Route::post('save', 'fileController@save');
```

Comment: define first `$insert = $request;` then  `$insert['file'] = $profilefile;`

Answer (score 0):

first of all if you want to store the images then you should store it using **Storage** feature of laravel. let me show you only the code for uploading the image and save it in database.

```
if($request->hasFile('file')){
        $file = $request->file('file');
        $fileName = time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
        Storage::put('public/file'.$fileName,file_get_contents($file));
        //file is uploaded and now you can store the name of the file in database 
    }
```

please add `use Storage` on top of the controller file.

now you can access it in this way:

```
<img src="{{asset('storage/file'.$namefromdatabase)}}" >
```

don't forget to run this command `php artisan storage:link` before uploading pictures in storage directory

Answer (score 0):

```
public function save(Request $request)
        {
           $insert=[];
           request()->validate(['file'  => 'required|mimes:doc,docx,pdf,txt,jpeg,jpg|max:2048',]);
    
           if ($files = $request->file('fileUpload')) {
               $destinationPath = 'public/file/'; // upload path
               $profilefile = date('YmdHis') . "." . $files->getClientOriginalExtension();
               $files->move($destinationPath, $profilefile);
               $insert['file'] = "$profilefile";
            }
            $check = Document::insertGetId($insert);
            return Redirect::to("file")
            ->withSuccess('Great! file has been successfully uploaded.');
        }
```

$insert is defined in this code, please try it.

Comment: Why should OP try this one? What was OP doing wrong? What did you change?

Comment: $insert was not define.so i just make it define.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line:

```
$insert['file'] = "$profilefile";
```

This says that in the presumably associated array called `$insert` the element with the key of `'file'` will have the value of `"$profilefile"` from now on. Your code crashes, because `$insert` was not initialized. Apparently the interpreter of PHP was not as smart as you and did not know that `$insert` should be an associated array. You will need to have a line of the like of

```
$insert = [];
```

which would define insert as an array. Note that this line must be executed before you assign values to the elements of `$insert`.